# Google API PHP Login retrieving Auth Error

Tags: php, oauth-2.0, google-api, google-oauth, google-plus

I am trying to implement a log in via Google on my application to access some information and control some features of the user Youtube channel but it is returning error all the time, saying that the user is not authenticated.

That's my code.

```
<?php
session_start();
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

$OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID = '-----------------------------------------';
$OAUTH2_CLIENT_SECRET = '-----------------';
$REDIRECT = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
$APPNAME = "Test";

try{
    $client = new Google_Client();
    $client->setClientId($OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID);
    $client->setClientSecret($OAUTH2_CLIENT_SECRET);
    $client->setScopes([
        'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.force-ssl',
        'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email',
        'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me',
        'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile'
    ]);
    $client->setRedirectUri($REDIRECT);
    $client->setApplicationName($APPNAME);
    $client->setDeveloperKey('---------------------');
    $client->setAccessType('offline');
    $client->setApprovalPrompt('force');
}
catch(Exception $e){
    die('1: '.$e);
}

$youtube = new Google_Service_YouTube($client);
$google_oauth = new Google_Service_Oauth2($client);
$plusAuth = new Google_Service_Plus($client);

if (isset($_GET['code'])) { 
    if (strval($_SESSION['state']) !== strval($_GET['state'])) {
        die('The session state did not match.');
    }
    
    try{
        $client->authenticate($_GET['code']);
        
        $user_email = $google_oauth->userinfo->get()->email;
        $user_name = $plusAuth->people->get('me')->displayName;
    }
    catch(Exception $e){
        die('2: '.$e);
    }
    
    // Code in between
    
    $_SESSION['token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
}

if (isset($_SESSION['token'])) {
    $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['token']);
    //echo "Access Token: " . json_encode($_SESSION['token']);
    
    header('Location: /main.php');
}


if ($client->getAccessToken()) {
    $_SESSION['token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
} 
else{
    $state = mt_rand();
    $client->setState($state);
    $_SESSION['state'] = $state;

    header('Location: '.$client->createAuthUrl());
}
?>
```

And I am getting this error:

```
2: Google_Service_Exception: { "error": { "code": 401, "message": "Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.", "errors": [ { "message": "Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.", "domain": "global", "reason": "unauthorized" } ], "status": "UNAUTHENTICATED" } }
```

I can't find the reason to the login flow is failing, but when it tries to use the properties of the Google Service Class's it always says that I am not authenticated.

If you can help me I am very welcome.

Comment: Which one of the API calls is throwing the Exception? I'm not seeing any of the numbered prefixes in your quoted error message.

Comment: Edited now. It is the second one.

Comment: I'd start by checking what value $_GET['code'] holds. Please note that isset() does not check for the existence of a value, it would merely report that the 'code' parameter was passed.

Comment: 4/nQBF4vLSGmzkPjGW-SqqkgUWRSM8HJHU8KtFRex0yrEMvjJOUijKya-D4Gzth2hDdV_lDh4KR3gnGPhO6dCITsE2 (it has the correct code passed by the authentification)

Comment: Ok. See if any of the scopes are causing the issue. Start by commenting all but one, and use a process of elimination.

Comment: Found the error. Stupid as always... The redirect uri (http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]) was returning the parameters and when tries to authenticate it was returning "redirect uri mismatch"

Comment: @RicardoPereira I'm getting the same error you were. But I don't understand how you solved it. What do you mean "when tries to authenticate it was returning 'redirect uri mismatch' "? I don't understand what your problem was…